# C# implicit cast for generic struct

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a generic class that acts as some wrapper for my other classes that are wrappers for some defined BCL classes :)

I want to create implicit cast from original BCL class to my using the intermediate class.
To be clear here is an example:

```
    public interface IWrapper<T>{

    }
    public struct IntWrapper : IWrapper<int>{
        public IntWrapper(int i)
        {
        }
    }

    public struct MainWrapper<T, TW> where TW: IWrapper<T>
    {
        public TW field;

        public static implicit operator MainWrapper<T, TW>(int val) 
            => new MainWrapper<T, TW>{field = new IntWrapper(val)}; // <-- Here the code fails
    }
```

The code fails with error that IntWrapper can not be casted to TW.
What I tried:

- Explicit cast `(TW)new IntWrapper(val)`
- Explicit set of return values types `new MainWrapper<int, IntWrapper>`
- Explicit set of return types `MainWrapper<int, IntWrapper>(int val)`

None of them works and fails for different reasons.

Is there a way to do this cast?

**Update**

If I move this implicit casts to intermediate type and split into 2 casts (from int to IntWrapper and then from IntWrapper to MainWrapper) it works.

But in this case In the usage method I need to help compiler to find the chain of casts through adding explicit cast to this intermediate class:

```
    public interface IWrapper<T>
    {

    }
    public struct IntWrapper : IWrapper<int>
    {
        public IntWrapper(int i)
        {
        }

        public static implicit operator IntWrapper(int val)
            => new IntWrapper(val);

        public static implicit operator MainWrapper<int, IntWrapper>(IntWrapper val)
            => new MainWrapper<int, IntWrapper> { field = val };

    }

    public struct MainWrapper<T, TW> where TW : IWrapper<T>
    {
        public TW field;
    }

    public class UseExample
    {
        public void Do(MainWrapper<int, IntWrapper> data){}

        public void Test()
        {
            Do((IntWrapper)1);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to help compiler to find this chain without explicit cast on a usage side?

Comment: With C#11 I think you can force `IntWrapper` to define a static factory method; `IWrapper<TW,T>{ static abstract TW Factory(T value); } class IntWrapper : IWrapper<IntWrapper,int>{...}` that you could then use in your generic implicit operator.

Comment: Not sure i got your answer. What is TW in IWrapper? Is it a static interface member? Never saw it, can you give links to the docs?

Answer (score 3):

You get the error since your `TW` type is not the same as `IWrapper<int>`. After all you could write your assignment like `MainWrapper<int, MyOtherIntWrapper> i = 5;`, and `MyOtherIntWrapper` is not the same as `IntWrapper`, even if they happen to implement the same interface.

If you change your code a bit you can get rid of that specific error:

```
public struct MainWrapper<T> 
{
    public IWrapper<T> field;

    public static implicit operator MainWrapper<int>(int val)
        => new MainWrapper<int> { field = new IntWrapper(val) };
}
```

But you still get an *User defined conversion must convert from or to the enclosing type*-error. Because `MainWrapper<int>` is not the same thing as `MainWrapper<T>`. The only way I know to avoid this would be to declare the conversion on the int-type, but that is obviously not possible.

You could force the cast:

```
public static implicit operator MainWrapper<T, TW>(int val)
            => new MainWrapper<T, TW> { field = (TW)((object)(new IntWrapper(val))) };
```

But that is really not something I would recommend. While `MainWrapper<int, IWrapper<int>> i1 = 5;` would work, `MainWrapper<int[], IWrapper<int[]>> i2 = 5;` will fail at *runtime*, and that is much worse.

So in the end I would suggest that you reconsider whatever it is you are trying to do. Generics are great as long as you can accept *any* type:

```
public struct MainWrapper<T> {
    public T field;
    public static implicit operator MainWrapper<T>(T val) => new MainWrapper<T> { field = val }; 
}
```

But as sone as you start introducing type specific stuff it tend to get messy.

Comment: I got another question reading your comment

After you said "The only way I know to avoid this would be to declare the conversion on the int-type, but that is obviously not possible." I realied that I can add 2 implicit converters to IntWrapper class - one from int and one to MainWrapper<int>. It works fine.
But to use it I need 2x conversions. E.g. this works:

 public void Do(MainWrapper<int, IntWrapper> data){}
 Do((IntWrapper)1);

But if I remove this explicit cast to intermediate class - it cant find the chain.
Is it possible to help compiler to find a chain of conversions?

Comment: Ok, I have found that comments here are quite ugly, so I edit my main post with Update section for this followup question.

Comment: @ApmeM It is frowned upon to edit questions to add follow up questions. The recommendations is to post a new question. However, as far as I know there is no way to have the compiler do multiple implicit casts. There are several problems with that approach, one that it would make compiling quite a bit more complicated and slow.

Answer (score 0):

With a generic constraint, you can only enforce that a type has an empty constructor. For other constructors you can assume that `Activator.CreateInstance` will work, but will risk throwing runtime errors.

In C#11, while you still can't enforce or call a particular constructor, you can define [`static abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) interface members. So your interface can enforce that the implementation implements a static method to act as a factory method.

Note, with a "curiously recursive" constraint, the interface can define the actual return type of this factory, instead of returning a boxed instance of the interface.

```cs
public interface IWrapper<T, TW>
    where TW : IWrapper<T, TW>
{
    static abstract TW Factory(T value);
}

public struct IntWrapper : IWrapper<IntWrapper, int>
{
    public static IntWrapper Factory(int value)
        => new IntWrapper(value);
}
```

Then in generic code, you can call this factory method based on the type of a generic parameter;

```
public static implicit operator MainWrapper<T, TW>(T val)
    where TW : IWrapper<T, TW>
    => new MainWrapper<T, TW>{ field = TW.Factory(val) };
```